# Error while deploying Laravel App on Vercel Project

Tags: laravel, deployment, vite, vercel

So I am trying to deploy Laravel on Vercel from [php-laravel](https://github.com/juicyfx/vercel-examples/tree/master/php-laravel)
but I am getting the below error.

> ```
>  Downloading user files
>  Downloading PHP runtime files
>  Installing Composer dependencies [START]
> php: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.10: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> Error: Exited with 127
>     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/vercel/path1/.vercel/builders/node_modules/vercel-php/dist/utils.js:178:24)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:518:28)
>     at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:488:12)
>     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
> Error: Command "vercel build" exited with 1
> Command "vercel build" exited with 1
> ```

Could someone please help me fix this? I tried other methods, but I am getting the same error. I tried putting custom installation commands but it didn't work.